# Country ISO and World region in Views

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, 4.6

There is no Views relationship to civicrm_country nor civicrm_worldregions. How to create a view counting number of contacts from a region?

Answer (score 3):

As of CiviCRM Entity 2.0-beta8 the Views relationships to Country and World Region have been made available. You must install the CiviCRM Entity Views Extras submodule.

CiviCRM Entity can be downloaded here:
https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity